# Woocommerce - Show a bundle in cart even if it's quantity is zero

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle

`Wordpress 4.9.4`, `WooCommerce 3.3.4` and `Product Bundles 5.7.7.`
When I **add bundled** item into **cart**, cart is filled with the **bundle**.
All i want is that i can ***remove*** some products from the **bundle**, like `minimum=0` or add an remove button.

The problem is, when i fill in Minimum Quantity of zero in the bundle plugin, add the **Bundle** to the cart and haven't **increased** the quantity of the zero-quantity bundled items, then they do not show up in the cart.

The standard woocommerce code is:

> only products with quantity greater than zero can display in the cart.

Is there any solution to allow a minimum of zero in the cart?
Or just remove a bundled product with a button?

Comment: I tested it out and I could add a product with two bundled items each with a quantity of zero and they appeared in my cart.